# Flutter how do I give constraints to this gesturedetector?

Tags: flutter, draggable, gesturedetector

What I'm trying to achieve is to drag the widget anywhere on the screen.
The solution below allows me to drag but goes beyond the limit of the screen.

Are there any max/min function I can apply here or the corresponding calculation to keep the widget inside the height and width of the screen.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
      return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/due.jpeg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Scaffold(
                  extendBody: true,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  body: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned(
                          left: offset.dx,
                          top: offset.dy,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onPanUpdate: (details) {
                              setState(() {
                                offset = (Offset(offset.dx + details.delta.dx,
                                    offset.dy + details.delta.dy));
                              });
     
                            },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any max/min function I can apply here

You can use `clamp` method:

```dart
double limitX = (offset.dx + details.delta.dx).clamp(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
double limitY = (offset.dy + details.delta.dy).clamp(lowerLimit, upperLimit);

offset = Offset(limitX, limitY);
```

> to keep the widget inside the **height** and **width** of the screen.

Use:

```dart
double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

And to apply the constraints to bottom and right you need to know the constraints of the object you're working with.

If you have them you can apply the computation:

```dart
Size objectSize = // the size of the object you're applying the constraints

double upperLimitX = screenWidth - objectSize.width;
double upperLimitY = screenHeight - objectSize.height;
```

You can check this working example at [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ffa4ca0bda81e4978d698ae0a28f007a) and on this [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/alexrintt/ffa4ca0bda81e4978d698ae0a28f007a).

[image: flutter clamp sample]

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried the clamp method like so below.
It successfully limited the widget to the inside of the Left and Top screen.
How can I modify it to also include the bottom and right screen?

double limitX = (offset.dx + details.delta.dx)
                                  .clamp(0, screenWidth);

                              double limitY = (offset.dy + details.delta.dy)
                                  .clamp(0, screenHeight);
                              setState(() {
                                offset = Offset(limitX, limitY);
                              });

Comment: You need to know the size of the object you're applying the constraints, so we can set `limitX` upperLimit to `screenWidth - objectWidth` and same for limitY but with height.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your patience Alex.
It solved my issue.
If you don't mind explaining why it is important to include the object's width and height when doing this calculation.

Comment: Try editing these values in the editor, it's easier to understand. Try removing the object size and setting only the `offsetX = screenWidth` and `offsetY = screenHeight`. It happens because top and left are relative to the origin of the object (a point), not the object itself (a 2d shape).

Answer (score 1):

when you calculate the new offset check for dy and dx to be inside view.
for example check offset.dx + details.delta.dx is bigger than 0 and smaller than MediaQuery.of(context).size.width then add this to new offset